# How to keep all webclient text in one line in Skype?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a issue with visual basic 2012 Webclients. I'm trying to gather information from a website. Then upload it to a Skype chat. On the website, the text goes in separate lines. **Example:**

Hello.

How Are You?

Good Thanks.

When I run the application, it displays the text in a odd way. It displays it like this:

```
<br>Hello<br>how are you&<br><br>good<br>
```

Here is the code. (This project is based around a Skype Bot, So I will need to blank out the api for this.)

```
 ElseIf msg.StartsWith("cloudflare ") Then
                    c.SendMessage("SkypeBot >" + vbNewLine +
                                  ("" + New WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("api" & msg.Replace("cloudflare ", ""))))
```

The issue is based around .DownloadStringTaskAsync I believe. Help with this issue will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I also know about "You need to use HTML on a web page to get line breaks. For example "
" will give you a line break."
but I'm unsure where to insert it and how to use it in that code.

Answer (score 0):

My VB.NET knowledge is a little rusty, but can you not use something like this (C# code):

```
string[] arrayOfText = welcomeText.split("<br>");
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the text. Stick it back together, but with spaces instead of < br>

Alternatively you could use the .replace function?